# can the iteration number of pbkdf2 be a security flaw?

Tags: hash, pbkdf2, sha256

I am now working on a project that involves saving two different pbkdf2 hashes on the server. i was wondering whether there is a mathematical connection between a 1000 iterations hash of a given password, and a 1001 iterations hash of the same password?

Comment: Since math is involved on all steps to create the hash from there password the must obviously some kind of mathematical connection, although not a trivial one. In any case: you should not use a fixed salt for storing passwords so the chance is high that the salt is different. This makes makes the mathematical connection even more complex. Apart from that I don't think that the title of your question really matches what you actually ask.

Comment: I'm not great on the exact crypto math, but the possibility that the code suffers an edge case off by one comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iteration structure of PBKDF2 looks like this (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-5.2):

```
U_1 = PRF (P, S || INT (i))
U_2 = PRF (P, U_1)
... 
U_{c - 1} = PRF(P, U_{c - 2})
U_c = PRF (P, U_{c-1})
```

Where:

- PRF is the Pseudo Random Function (i.e. the underlying hash function)
- P is the password
- S is the salt
- i is the block number

Given U_{c - 1} and U_c, I could try to find P such that U_c = PRF (P, U_{c-1}) rather than having to iterate 1000 times as you'd normally have to with PBKDF2.

This essentially defeats having multiple iterations in the KDF, reducing the number of calls to the PRF from 1000 times per try to the smallest difference between any two hashes' iteration count.

An improvement if you need multiple PBKDF2 with different iteration count from the same password, is to vary the Salt.

Comment: *"Given U_{c - 1} and U_c"* - You don't have U_{c-1}. Only the derived keys DK_c and DK_{c-1} are given which are based on XOR U_1, U_2, ..... By having DK_c and DK_{c-1} you might compute U_c (using XOR) but not U_{c-1}. And I think only the knowledge of U_c does not make the attack significantly easier.

Comment: Yes, you're correct that having just the hashes from two different iteration count probably won't let you get `U_{c - 1}` easily. Having three consecutive hashes should allow you to trivially calculate `U_{c - 1}`, right?

Comment: Correct. If you have DK_{c-1} and DK_{c-2} you can compute U_{c-1} the same way you can compute U_c from DK_c and DK_{c-1}.